# Como diferenciar variável (inputs) no mesmo form do Django

Tags: django

bom dia!
Tenho a seguinte questão:

Tenho uma classe Pessoa, da qual posso ter 3 tipos de pessoa
(Vítima, Agressor e Testemunha) no mesmo formulário... como eu faria para setar as variáveis de forma que ao salvar no banco sejam 3 atributos diferentes

ex.

Formulário de crimes contra a vida

VÍTIMA

fom_vida.name

AGRESSOR

form_vida.name

TESTEMUNHA

form-vida.name

Isso no mesmo form, ou seja, eu quero diferenciar as variáveis!

Olá renan. eu não entendi sua resposta:

```
class ForensicAgressor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Nome')
    birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data de Nascimento')

class ForensicVitima(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Nome')
birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data de Nascimento')


class ForensicPessoa(models.Model):
    agressor = models.ForeignKey(ForensicAgressorn)
    vitima = models.ForeignKey(ForensicVitima)
```

veja acima como está, como que eu faria no mesmo Form para setar o valor (input) de cada objeto?

Comment: Se vítima, agressor e testemunha são objetos de uma mesma classe, talvez seja necessário adicionar um atributo à classe, por exemplo, `role` ("papel"). Daí uma pessoa pode ter `name = "fulano"` e `role = "agressor"`, outra pode ter `name = "beltrano"` e `role = "testemunha"` etc.

Comment: Olá Renan, eu não entendi sua resposta, veja acima, eu tentei reformular a questão

Comment: Olá, Sara. Eu nunca usei Django. Estava imaginando como a aplicação distinguiria uma vítima de um agressor, por exemplo, apenas olhando pelo banco de dados. É que você mencionou uma classe pessoa, mas eu não tinha visto que há três classes distintas.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from django import forms

# Author: Ruben Alves do Nascimento <rubenanapu@hotmail.com>


class Pessoa(models.Model):
    VITIMA = 1
    AGRESSOR = 2
    TESTEMUNHA = 3

    TIPOS_PESSOA = (
        (VITIMA, 'Vítima'),
        (AGRESSOR , 'Agressor'),
        (TESTEMUNHA, 'Testemunha'),
    )

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Nome na pessoa')
    tipo = models.IntegerField(choices=TIPOS_PESSOA, help_text='Tipo de pessoa')


class Vitima(Pessoa):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tipo = self.VITIMA
        super(Vitima, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Agressor(Pessoa):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tipo = self.AGRESSOR
        super(Agressor, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Testemunha(Pessoa):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tipo = self.TESTEMUNHA
        super(Testemunha, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class VitimaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vitima
        exclude = ('tipo', )

class AgressorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Agressor
        exclude = ('tipo', )

class TestemunhaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Testemunha
        exclude = ('tipo', )


######## agora, supondo que a pessoa submeteu o form com a variavel nome
# Para registrar uma vítima
nome = 'Sou vitima'
pessoa = Vitima(nome=nome)
pessoa.save()

# Para registrar um agressor
nome = 'Sou agressor'
pessoa = Agressor(nome=nome)
pessoa.save()

# Para registrar uma testemunha
nome = 'Sou testemunha'
pessoa = Testemunha(nome=nome)
pessoa.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes ter no mesmo Form 3 botões para tratar das diferentes submissões.

```
<button type="submit" value="some_value" name="Agressor">some_value</button>
...
<button type="submit" value="some_value" name="Vitima">some_value</button>
...
<button type="submit" value="some_value" name="Pessoa">some_value</button>
```

Na tua view consegues diferenciar os diferentes POST's fazendo:

```
if request.POST.get('Agressor'):
...
if request.POST.get('Vitima'):
...
if request.POST.get('Pessoa'):
```

Comment: De facto a resposta do @renan faz sentido. Uma Pessoa tem um agressor e uma vitima?